# Problems accessing Service Fabric Cluster via RDP

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I'm trying to access my service fabric cluster to see the files in it via RDP, but when I use `mstsc /v:mycluster.brazilsouth.cloudapp.azure.com:3389` the following error message shows up:

Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled

2) The remote computer is turned off

3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

How do I enable my cluster to allow RDP connection?

Just say if you need more infos.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the load balancer deployed in the same resource group. There you'll find the RDP ports forwarded to the VM instances. If there aren't any, just add some. It's just a scale set fronted by a load balancer, nothing special.

Comment: In "Frontend IP configuration" option?

Comment: It's in "Inbound NAT Rules".

Comment: @GuilhermeMendonca Could your RDP other instances, you could change port to 3390, 3391..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SF cluster instances is a VMSS, by default, Azure opens RDP port on Load Balancer, you don't need change anything. You could find the RDP port on Azure Portal. `<your resource group>--><Load balancer>--><Settings>--><Inbound NAT rules>`.

[image]

According to your description, please ensure your VMSS instance is running.

[image]

Comment: I've checked VMSS instances, and it's running... I got the same error message for all the 5 nodes when trying to access through ports (3389-3393).

Comment: @GuilhermeMendonca If possible, could you try restart your VMSS. What do you do in your instance?

Comment: @GuilhermeMendonca By default, SF cluster allows you RDP to instances. What you are doing? I suggest you could restart your instance and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes#remote-connect-to-a-vm-scale-set-instance-or-a-cluster-node.